# Загрузка файла с api-route, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Есть такая схема сайта: `интерфейс пользователя(он же фронт) -=> back-end этого фронта -=> api`.

Пользователю нужно скачать большой файл(прим.ссылки `http://domain/api/123.iso`). `api` требует в заголовках ключ клиента, который является приватным.

Код загрузки файла со стороны `api`:

```
$headers = array(
            'Content-Description'       => 'File Transfer',
            'Content-Type'              => File::mimeType($path),
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
            'Expires'                   => 0,
            'Cache-Control'             => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
            'Pragma'                    => 'public',
            'Content-Length'            => File::size($path),
            'Content-Disposition'       =>  'attachment; filename="'.$name.'"'
        );
        $response = new Response('', 200, $headers);
        $response->sendHeaders();

        if(ob_start()) ob_end_clean();
        if ($fp = fopen($path, 'rb')) {
            while(!feof($fp)) {
                print(fread($fp, 8192));
                flush();
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }
        exit;
```

Как мне организовать приём этого ответа со стороны `backend` и отдать пользователю?

**P.S.** Идеи которые приходили в голову.

1. Скачивание должно происходить при отправке формы(прямой переход) на адрес(`http://domain/api/downloads/{filename}`). Соответственно, контроллер `Downloads` будет отдавать {filename}. Зачем форма - что-бы установить ключ в отдельный input. Но это противоречит тому, что ключ api приватный, ведь можно посмотреть что было отправлено.
2. `Танцы с бубном`. Код загрузчика на `backend`:

   ```
   $options = array(
      'http' => [
          'method' => 'GET',
          'header' => 'x-api: '.env('API_KEY')
      ]
   );
   $context = stream_context_create($options);
   $file = fopen(env('API_URL').'/library/test/download', 'r', false, $context);
   $headers = stream_get_meta_data($file);
   //decode header 'base-headers' to array, format 'base-header: {json_string}'
   $h = (array)json_decode(str_replace('base-headers:', '', $headers['wrapper_data'][3]));
   $response = new Response('', 200, $h);
   $response->sendHeaders();
   while(!feof($file)) {
       print(fread($file, 8192));
   }
   fclose($file);
   exit;
   ```

   Код обработки на `api` прежний, кроме заголовка:

   ```
   $headers = array(
       'Content-Description'       => 'File Transfer',
       'Content-Type'              => File::mimeType($path),
       'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
       'Expires'                   => 0,
       'Cache-Control'             => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
       'Pragma'                    => 'public',
       'Content-Length'            => File::size($path),
       'Content-Disposition'       =>  'attachment; filename="'.$name.'"'
   );
   //$response = new Response('', 200, $headers);
   $h = [
      'base-headers' => json_encode($headers)
   ];
    $response = new Response('', 200, $h);
   ```

   При таком раскладе ОЗУ забивается в арифметической прогрессии - 1 загрузка(1,5 GB) ~ 30 Mb, что не есть хорошо.

Прошу Вашей помощи и подсказок в этом направлении.